# Run node server (socket.io) on Vagrant and reach them from browser

Tags: node.js, angular, laravel, socket.io, vagrant

I use Laravel for backend in my project, and for chat purpose I use Redis. On my PC I have Windows and regarding to that I run Laravel/Redis application on Vagrant. Also I setup node server for socket.io on Vagrant, and communication between Laravel/Redis application and that server works fine.

Problem is on client side where I use Angular, I can't connect client side on socket.io server run on Vagrant, I don't know what address to use to subscribe on client side.

This is my node server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use('/', express.static('www'));

http.listen(3000, '192.168.10.10', function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

client.on('message', function(chan, msg) {
    console.log(chan);
    console.log(msg);
    io.sockets.emit(chan, msg);
});

client.subscribe('add-message');
```

On client side:

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://192.168.10.10:3000', options: {} };
```

But when I start application I get error that application can't subscribe to server.

Does anyone knows how I can reach node server started on Vagrant from browser or some another IP address in my private network?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is Vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 2.1.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON::parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostsupdater')
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    elsif Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
        config.hostmanager.enabled = true
        config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
        config.hostmanager.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end
end
```

Comment: Is the client app running on Windows or the Vagrant box?

Comment: client app running on Windows, that is the problem, and must running outside from Vagrant

Comment: Can you share some of your vagrant config? Perhaps the network is not correct to view from the host machine (might need to forward ports or change to public network).

Comment: I share Vagrant file in edit of question

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any configuration for networking yet in your config which is most likely your problem. Try following the steps here to forward ports from the virtual machine to your host or by placing the host on a private network: https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/networking.html

Comment: Do you know where I should write those line of codes in my Vagrant file, and allow port 3000 outside from vagrant?

Comment: Add between this block: `Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|`